# MyHDL: Unary XOR

Tags: verilog, myhdl

How to write myhdl code to implement Unary XOR in verilog

```
reg [63:0] large_bus;
wire xor_value;
assign xor_value = ^large_bus;
```

doesn't work for me.

```
@block
def dataVecXor(large_bus, xor_value):
    @always_comb
    def outputlogic():
        xor_value.next = ^large_bus
return instances()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [solution](https://github.com/myhdl/myhdl/issues/289) On MyHDL's issue tracker:

```py
large_bus = Signal(intbv(0)[128:0])
xor_value = Signal(bool(0))

@always_comb
def beh_reduction_xor():
    x = large_bus[0]
    for ii in range(1, len(large_bus)):
        x = x ^ large_bus[ii]
    xor_value.next = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct what you want by using 'for'.